# How to add a managed path in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How to add a managed path in sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here full documentation is available..

 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845.aspx
```

Answer (score 2):

follow below steps to add a managed path by using Central Administration
Verify that the user account that is performing this task is a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group.

On the SharePoint Central Administration Web site, click Application Management.

On the Application Management page, click Manage Web Applications.

Click the Web application for which you want to manage paths. The ribbon becomes active.

On the ribbon, click Managed Paths.

On the Define Managed Paths page, in the Add a New Path section, type the path to include.

Click Check URL to confirm the path name.

Use the Type dropdown menu to identify the path as either Wildcard inclusion or Explicit inclusion. The Wildcard inclusion type includes all paths that are subordinate to the specified path. The Explicit inclusion type includes only the site that is indicated by the specified path. Sites subordinate to the specified path are not included.

Click Add Path.

When you have finished adding paths, click OK.
for more information please varify this link http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/zach/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=30